# Variable elimination in Bayes Net

Tags: artificial-intelligence

We have studied the Variable Elimination recently and the teacher emphasizes that it is the Bayesian Network that makes varibale elimination more efficient.
I am bit confused on this,why is this the case?
Hope you guys can give me some idea,many thanks.

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because a variable which one can eliminate is one which has one and only one variable which is dependent on it.  In a Bayes net these would be easy to find because they are nodes with a single child.

Answer (score 2):

Bayesian Networks can take advantage of the order of variable elimination because of the conditional independence assumptions built in.

Specifically, imagine having the joint distribution P(a,b,c,d) and wanting to know the marginal P(a). If you knew nothing about the conditional independence, you could calculate this by summing out over b,c and d. If these have k-ary domains, you need to do O(k^3) operations.

On the other hand, assume that you have a bayes net where A is the root, B is a child of A, C is a child of B and D is a child of C. Then, you can rewrite the joint as P(a|b)P(b|c)P(c|d)P(d) and distribute your three summations as far to the right of the equation as possible. When you actually want to compute P(a), you can precompute the value of sum_d P(d) and store this function. Likewise, you can precompute the value of P(c|d)*sum_d P(d) and store this.

In this way, you end up doing work of O(k^w*+1), where W* is the largest number of children any node in your bayes net has. In this case, we do O(k^2) work, which is also the size of the largest conditional probability table we must keep in memory. Note this is better than our original O(k^3) result, and would be even better if we had more variables.

In short, the conditional independence of a BN allows you to marginalize out variables more efficiently. Another explanation of this can be found at http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp08/cs440/notes/varElimLec.pdf.

Comment: This looks like you ended up explaining something completely different.

Comment: It is possible I misunderstood, but this is a big reason BNs are more efficient for variable elimination, because of the ability to take advantage of the conditional independence assumptions. 

Variable Elimination is a term which usually refers to the idea of marginalizing out variables. If you just want to remove a node from the network, then the first answer suffices. In my experience, when VE is capitalized and we're talking about Bayes Nets, it refers to the first situation.